# fetch devuelve undefined

Tags: javascript, php, json, fetch

hola soy nuevo en esto de fetch y al momento de hacer el log me devuelve un undefined les muestro

```
let url = "productobuy.php";
let data = {username: 'example'};
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
    body: JSON.stringify(data), // data can be `string` or {object}!
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }).then(res => res.json())
  .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
  .then(response => console.log('Success:', response));
```

la consola del navegador me arroja esto[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

espero su ayuda gracias

este es el php que es solo un archivo :

```
<?php
$input =trim( file_get_contents('php://input'));
$input=json_decode($input,true);
print_r ($input);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="js5.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

no me aparece el post que envio en el php[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: *`Unexpected character`* significa que en el servidor no se está produciendo un JSON válido. ¿Podrías mostrar el código de servidor que maneja tu petición fetch pulsando en [edit]? Cuando pides un JSON debes hilar fino en el servidor, cuidando de no emitir ningún otro tipo de salida que no sea un JSON válido. A veces se imprimen mensajes de error, o bloques HTML o cualquier otra salida por pantalla que rompe el eventual JSON que el cliente está esperando, ocurriendo el error que ahora tienes.

Comment: ahi puse mi phjp

Comment: Justo lo que te he dicho en mi primer comentario. El `print_r` sobra y todo el bloque `<!DOCTYPE html>` también. El archivo PHP que recibe la petición de fetch sólo es para gestionar los datos y devolver una respuesta en el formato contratado. Si en este caso es un JSON, ese archivo debe devolver únicamente un JSON válido, nada más.

Comment: Asumiendo que `$input` es un json válido, la única salida que debe tener ese código es un `echo json_encode($input);` Aunque es muy raro, porque devuelves lo mismo que recibiste ¿? Lo normal es recibir algo, usarlo para obtener ciertos datos y devolver esos nuevos datos.

Comment: En la pestaña `Network`  del navegador, concretamente  en `Fetch/XHR`  Tendras mas pistas sobre su request al documento  `productobuy.php`

Comment: ahora me funciona el fetch, pero no me aparece el post en el php al que lo envio

Comment: quiero guardar esos datos en un base de datos